# "Cannot GET /index.html" error while running a node.js and express application but I don't have any index.html

Tags: html, node.js, linux, express, ejs

I can't understand why I am getting this error. It is working well on my local machine but giving this error when I am running on Linux. I have made ejs files also added all the required stuff. Also, I don't have an index.html file.
All my files are at the right locations.

```
    const app = express();
    
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
      res.render("home");
    });
```

Comment: How are you making the request to the server?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Are you making the request to the server from a browser? If so what URL are you trying to access?

Comment: I am able to open other parts but I am not able to open home page

Comment: What is the endpoint for the home page? `/` ?

Comment: like if I enter url/events then it is opening but the home page is giving this error

Comment: You are also serving static files on `/`, maybe that is causing the issue? Try serving static files on a different endpoint.

Comment: it ends with .ac.in

Comment: Does using `app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname+"/public"));` instead of `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));` make any difference?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that, I am a beginner so I don't know much

Comment: Replace the `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));` with `app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname+"/public"));`

Comment: it is same, no changes

Comment: also I am not able to understand how others are working but home one is not

Comment: Where do you see the `Cannot GET index.html` error?

Comment: after entring my url

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your home.ejs is inside views directory .